# IE 8, Stack overflow on Jquery operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, stack

I am using the following code to filter a table based on input from a text box. On every other browser I don't receive such an error but on IE 8 (haven't tested on lower) I receive the error:

```
Out of stack space Line 4 character 26207 jquery.min.js
```

Below is my current code causing the issue:

```
var timeout;

function sort(){

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    var value = document.getElementById('searchBarText').value;

    timeout = setTimeout(
    function(){$("#searchTable tr").each(function() {
        var id = " "  
            $row = $(this);
            $row.each(function( i ) {
                  $("td", this).each(function( j ) {
                  id+="".concat($(this).text());
                  });
                });
            id = id.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            id = id.replace(/(\d+)/g, '');
            if (id.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                $row.hide();
                if(value.length < 3){
                    $("#searchBarText").css('border', '2px red solid')
                }else{
                    $("#searchBarText").removeAttr('style')
                }
            }
            else if(value!="" &&value.length >= 3) {
                $("#searchBarText").removeAttr('style')
                $("#topTable").css('margin-top', '0px')
                $("#searchIcon").css('color', '#26466D')
                $("#searching").fadeIn();
                $row.show();
            }else{
                if(value.length > 0){
                    $("#searchBarText").css('border', '2px red solid')

                }else{
                    $("#searchBarText").removeAttr('style')
                }
                $("#searchIcon").removeAttr('style')
                $("#searching").slideUp();
                $("#topTable").css('margin-top', '-5px')
                $row.hide();
           }
    })},400);
}
```

Now the main time it happens, is when the search query is cleared, meaning all of the rows are then put back into the table.

I have a feeling the inefficiency is somewhere in here:

```
$row = $(this);
$row.each(function( i ) {
   $("td", this).each(function( j ) {
       id+="".concat($(this).text());
     });
});
```

I am by no means a javascript expert, so all help is appreciated!

UPDATE: Turns out it was the scroll up jquery method, replaced it with show and it was all set

Answer (score 3):

First I'd suggest that you don't select the same element more than once on the same operation, everytime you select something through jQuery, the DOM must be traversed in order to find it.
 So, for example, look for #searchBarText once and re use it, like this:

```
var $searchBarText = $('#searchBarText');
```

And as for the chunk of code you mentioned, I'll do that like this:

```
$row = $(this);
$row.children('td').each(function () {
    id += $(this).text();
});
```

Children() just looks on the first level of the element's content, so it's the fastest way.

Comment: I added both of your changes, and I'm sure they did help the efficiency so thanks for that. However, it seems that the error still occurs. A little debugging uncovered that this only happens when I delete the entirety of text at once (i.e. select all backspace). However, when I slowly press backspace after each character, the error does not occur. I am calling this function using onkeyup in the textfield

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate over each row when you only have one, just select the cells directly and iterate over them.

```
$row = $(this);
$row.find("td").each(function( i ) {
    id+=$(this).text();
});
```

or

```
$row = $(this);
id += $row.find("td").map(function( i ) {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join("");
```

or even

```
$row = $(this);
id += $row.text();
```